# Images uploading from media going in wrong folder

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, media

I am uploading images from Media section of WordPress. The images are uploading in 2016/12 instead of 2017/08. I checked for media setting in Settings > Media and Organise my uploads into month- and year-based folders option is selected.

Also when I create a new page and upload an image from there then it goes in 2017/08 folder.

Can anyone suggest me how I can fix it. I searched for this and didn't found solution for images issue uploading from Media section.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem! Using Eduma theme... what theme are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Something must be wrong with the *wp_upload_dir* function. In your *wp-includes* directory, look for a file called *functions.php*. Make sure *wp_upload_dir*  is set as follows:

```
function wp_upload_dir( $time = null, $create_dir = true, $refresh_cache = false ) {
    static $cache = array(), $tested_paths = array();

    $key = sprintf( '%d-%s', get_current_blog_id(), (string) $time );

    if ( $refresh_cache || empty( $cache[ $key ] ) ) {
        $cache[ $key ] = _wp_upload_dir( $time );
    }
```

Let me know if this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. The function looks fine in function.php file. I pasted the above code and tried again. Also i replace the function.php file with fresh function.php. Still the issue is there. Any other alternative..

Comment: I found this from a different site which might work. Try switching back to the default theme and deactivating all your plugins then check if uploads go to the right folder.

Comment: This will may effect the layout of my site. Some time deactivating theme and reactivating changes the options.. But i will try it and let you know.

Comment: Hopefully it doesn't mess with the layout. I'm looking for other potential causes in the meantime.